# Is there any feasible solution to read WOT battle results .dat files?

Tags: python

I am new here to try to solve one of my interesting questions in World of Tanks. I heard that every battle data is reserved in the client's disk in the Wargaming.net folder because I want to make a batch of data analysis for our clan's battle performances.
 [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDKNi.png)

It is said that these .dat files are a kind of json files, so I tried to use a couple of lines of Python code to read but failed.

```
import json
f = open('ex.dat', 'r', encoding='unicode_escape')
content = f.read()
a = json.loads(content)
print(type(a))
print(a)
f.close()
```

The code is very simple and obviously fails to make it. Well, could anyone tell me the truth about that?

Added on Feb. 9th, 2022
After I tried another set of codes via Jupyter Notebook, it seems like something can be shown from the .dat files

```
import struct
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io


with open('C:/Users/xukun/Desktop/br/ex.dat', 'rb') as f:
    fbuff = io.BufferedReader(f)
    N = len(fbuff.read())
    print('byte length: ', N)

    with open('C:/Users/xukun/Desktop/br/ex.dat', 'rb') as f:
        data =struct.unpack('b'*N, f.read(1*N))
```

The result is a set of tuple but I have no idea how to deal with it now.
[image]

Comment: Welcom to stack overflow. I don't know anything about WOT, so could you édit your question by adding the error message or the output you get when your code is executed ?

Comment: Hi, I am struggling on the same problem just now. 
The error we are getting by trying to open this .dat file is the following:
"""
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
"""

The .dat file is proprietary to a game called World of Tanks (WOT).

Comment: I strongly recommend that you start outside of Python using command line tools (which will depend on your OS) to try to determine the format of these WOT files. If they're JSON then you'll be able to view them (because they would just be text) in your favourite text editor. However, even though I know nothing about such files, I'm going to guess they're binary in nature

Comment: @PierrickRambaud  Thank you so much for the reply! The error message is **SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape** in JupyterNotebook. It is different from the message shown in Pycharm as gabzo said

Comment: @OlvinRoght Thanks for your advice. I tried _type (FileName)_ via cmd tool, but I only got a stack of Mojibake (garbled text). Actually, when I use Power BI to input these files, Power BI has determined they are binary files but cannot read them.

Comment: then it's not in json format, therefore you can't unpack them with ```json.loads()```

Comment: @MetroKun You **WILL** be able to open these files in Python using mode 'rb'. However, unless you know their internal structure it will be a rather pointless exercise

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can parse some parts of it.

```
import pickle
import zlib

file = '4402905758116487.dat'
cache_file = open(file, 'rb') # This can be improved to not keep the file opened.

# Converting pickle items from python2 to python3 you need to use the "bytes" encoding or "latin1". 
legacyBattleResultVersion, brAllDataRaw = pickle.load(cache_file, encoding='bytes', errors='ignore')

arenaUniqueID, brAccount, brVehicleRaw, brOtherDataRaw = brAllDataRaw

# The data stored inside the pickled file will be a compressed pickle again. 
vehicle_data = pickle.loads(zlib.decompress(brVehicleRaw), encoding='latin1')
account_data = pickle.loads(zlib.decompress(brAccount), encoding='latin1')
brCommon, brPlayersInfo, brPlayersVehicle, brPlayersResult = pickle.loads(zlib.decompress(brOtherDataRaw), encoding='latin1')


# Lastly you can print all of these and see a lot of data inside.
```

The response contains a mixture of more binary files as well as some data captured from the replays.
This is not a complete solution but it's a decent start to parsing these files.

Answer (score 0):

After loading the pickle files like gabzo mentioned, you will see that it is simply a list of values and without knowing what the value is referring to, its hard to make sense of it. The identifiers for the values can be extracted from your game installation:

```
import zipfile

WOT_PKG_PATH = "Your/Game/Path/res/packages/scripts.pkg"
BATTLE_RESULTS_PATH = "scripts/common/battle_results/"

archive = zipfile.ZipFile(WOT_PKG_PATH, 'r')

for file in archive.namelist():
    if file.startswith(BATTLE_RESULTS_PATH):
        archive.extract(file)
```

You can then decompile the python files(`uncompyle6`) and then go through the code to see the identifiers for the values.

One thing to note is that the list of values for the main pickle objects (like `brAccount` from gabzo's code) always has a checksum as the first value. You can use this to check whether you have the right order and the correct identifiers for the values. The way these checksums are generated can be seen in the decompiled python files.

I have been tackling this problem for some time (albeit in Rust): https://github.com/dacite/wot-battle-results-parser/tree/main/datfile_parser.

Answer (score 0):

First you can look at the replay file itself in a text editor. But it won't show the code at the beginning of the file that has to be cleaned out.  Then there is a ton of info that you have to read in and figure out but it is the stats for each player in the game. THEN it comes to the part that has to do with the actual replay. You don't need that stuff.

You can grab the player IDs and tank IDs from WoT developer area API if you want.